# Right usage of uuencode command

Tags: command-line

I tried to encode ASCII file, but it was stuck. Why & how to do it properly.

```
$ cat color2~
yellow
pink 
blue
$ uuencode color2~
begin 644 color2~
^C
```

Comment: Try `man uuencode`in a terminal, to see the manual page for uuencode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uuencode has not a easy syntax. But it still does its job

## Encode to stdout

```
$ uuencode color2 /dev/stdout
begin 664 /dev/stdout
1>65L;&]W"G!I;FL*8FQU90H`
`
end
```

## Encode to file

```
$ uuencode color2 outfile.txt > outfile.txt
$ cat outfile.txt 
begin 664 outfile.txt
1>65L;&]W"G!I;FL*8FQU90H`
`
end
```